# How to delete/replace first page in Word document using python

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I want to replace/delete first page of word document.
My first page doesn't contain any text. It is more of a template. I need to delete/ replace first page irrespective of the contents.
Is there a way to do that using python-docx?

Comment: How will your program know where the first page ends? See "Word Does Not Know What A Page Is" by Word MVP Daiya Mitchell: https://wordmvp.com/Mac/PagesInWord.html.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to delete specific section from the document?

Comment: There are lots of ways. However, you need to identify what it is you wish to delete. How can Python tell where the page ends? What marks the beginning of the second page? What marks the end of the first page? It may be a manual page break. It may be a Next-Page Section break. It may be a paragraph set to start a new page.

Comment: For now, the assumption is my first section is the first page. And we have a new page section break at the end. How can I delete/replace this first section?

Comment: I know Word, not python. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask